# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required

Tags: json, mongodb, python-3.x, pymongo

I am trying to insert values in MongoDB, but I am getting this error:

> ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required.

```
From pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient()

db = client.abc_database

keys = []
values = []
key = input("enter keys:").split(",")
keys.append(key)
print(keys)
print(keys[0][1])
value = input("enter values").split(",")
values.append(value)
print(values)
fin = []
k = 0
while k < len(keys[0]):
    d = keys[0][k] + ":" + values[0][k]
    fin.append(d)
    k += 1
print(fin)
fin_id = db.fin.insert(dict([fin]))
print("successful")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying construct a `dict` from key-value pairs by first concatenating each key to its value:

```
d = keys[0][k] + ":" + values[0][k]
```

Make the key-value pairs tuples instead:

```
d = keys[0][k], values[0][k]
```

Then you should be able to use `dict(fin)`. Note that `fin` is already a list; don't wrap in another list like you do in `dict([fin])`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I am able to insert more values now. It means a lot to me. ^_^ It's my second day with MongoDB and i was literally struggling. Same goes with my knowledge on Python. Gotta work a lot. Thanks again. @JanneKarila

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputations. :/

Comment: That's what the problem was i guess when i was  inserting documents in a collection. it was taking only 2 inputs. After using your solution, it's working great. @JanneKarila